# Can Guest Wifi admin see sub-pages or just main domain?

Tags: https

I am a newbie to tech world so forgive me.

Using my personal phone (not my work issued one), I clicked accidentally through to a NSFW twitter page.  I only spent 20 seconds or so on there before realising that I was connected to my Company’s guest WiFi.   They have had zero access to my device to install any sort of monitoring software.

My question is:  I understand that when accessing Https websites your ISP can see only the top layer domain ie twitter.com, but searching for twitter.com/news/UK the “/news/UK” would be encrypted?  Am I correct in this?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of routers now such as [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1010937/) can monitor what sites you went on. So let's say you went on `www.badsite.com` It would show up that site on the list + the MAC address you have assigned.

Comment: Thanks.  But can It see www.badsite.com/sky?  I had understood that with https the “/sky” is encrypted.

Comment: The DNS server and related servers might not; but the router comes before that. If they use that kind of router, it likely did record the entire address; however, if you dropped it the moment you noticed, and are in good standing, I very much doubt that you'll hear from them again. Those lists can get very, very, long; and since the twitter account clearly isn't flagged, a human being would probably have to spot it.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Can I PM you? (Is there a PM function on this thing?!)

Comment: @JimD I think you are fine. They will see www.badsite.com BUT not the /sky.

Comment: Thanks Zuck.  There seems to be quite a lot of debate on that point online.  Some people saying that everything after the “/“ is invisible, some saying the router logs the full URL.